# Overload resolution involving old-style enums and integral types

Tags: c++, enums, implicit-conversion, overload-resolution

Consider the following piece of code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

enum myEnum { a, b, c };

void test(myEnum e) {
  cout << "myEnum overload" << endl;
}

void test(unsigned int i) {
  cout << "unsigned int overload" << endl;
}

int main() {
  test(a);
  test(1);
  test(1u);  

  return 0;
}
```

(I know `enum class` is safer than `enum` for this kind of things but I am using open-source code that has old-style enums.)

When I compile this with g++ 4.4.7 and run it, I get

```
myEnum overload
unsigned int overload
unsigned int overload
```

i.e. the compiler prefers to convert `int` to `unsigned int` over converting it to `myEnum`.  This is what I want, but I was wondering if this is always guaranteed.  The standard does not specify exactly what the underlying type of `myEnum` should be, so I thought perhaps if it was exactly `int`, perhaps this would be favored over `unsigned int`.

But when I comment out the `unsigned int` overload, I get this error:

```
enum_overload.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
enum_overload.cpp:17: error: invalid conversion from ‘int’ to ‘myEnum’
enum_overload.cpp:17: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void test(myEnum)’
enum_overload.cpp:18: error: invalid conversion from ‘unsigned int’ to ‘myEnum’
enum_overload.cpp:18: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void test(myEnum)’
```

Does that mean that old-style enums implicitly convert *to* their underlying types but not *from* those types?  If that is the case, then that would answer my previous question: if integral types can't convert to `myEnum`, then the overload resolution is guaranteed to behave as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[conv.integral]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.integral#1):

> A prvalue of an unscoped enumeration type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of an integer type.

The converse is not true.  There's no implicit conversion from an integer type to an unscoped enum type:

It seems that you are confusing this with *casting* an integral value to an enum type: [[expr.static.cast]/10](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.static.cast#10)

> **A value of integral or enumeration type can be explicitly converted to a complete enumeration type.** The value is unchanged if the
>   original value is within the range of the enumeration values
>   ([dcl.enum]). Otherwise, the behavior is undefined. A value of
>   floating-point type can also be explicitly converted to an enumeration
>   type. The resulting value is the same as converting the original value
>   to the underlying type of the enumeration ([conv.fpint]), and
>   subsequently to the enumeration type.

(emphasis mine)

But this can only be done via an explicit cast:

```
E x1 = static_cast<E>(1) // yes
E x2 = E(1);             // yes
E x3 = 1;                // no
E x4(1);                 // no
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you read [this link](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/newbie#enumeration-is-its-own-type).

As mentioned,

> An enumeration such as `enum Color { red, white, blue };` is its own
>   type. It is not of type `int`.

`myEnum` is neither an `int` nor an `unsigned int`.

Plus, I suggest not to use `myEnum` by directly casting an `int` to a `myEnum` (doing this: `test(static_cast<myEnum>(0))`).
Indeed the compiler won't check for you if the value provided is a valid one, it can lead to unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks!  This also explains *why* conversion without cast is only possible in one direction: converting an enum to its underlying type will always give a valid value; in the other direction that's not the case.